# How to effectively store data into cache in Laravel 8 cache (File)?

Tags: php, laravel

We are trying to cache (in file) a large number of incoming requests count based on the some unique key and storing it with its key as a object.
**(For Example: Unique Key - unique & Value - 1)**

```
if(Cache::has($key.'Count')){
      $temp = Cache::get($key.'Count');
      $temp[] = 1;
      Cache::put($key.'Count',$temp,env('CACHE_TIMER_IN_SECONDS',300));
}
else{
      Cache::put($key.'Count',[1],env('CACHE_TIMER_IN_SECONDS',300));
}
```

We tried incrementing the count, or appending a value to the array (as in above code), but in all we loose some counts.

**So, now when a huge amount of request hit our API (400+ throughput/sec) We loose various count in our cache's object of that particular key.**

So is there any efficient way to store large amount of incoming request count into the cache without loosing any requests count for that particular key in the cache.

We have also created a scheduled task for every 2 minute to update in the database.

```
        $schedule->call(function () {
            $clients = Cache::get('consumed_clients');
            if($clients!=NULL){
                for ($l = 0; $l < count($clients[0]); $l++) {
                    $clientObj = Cache::get($clients[0][$l]);
                    if(is_array(Cache::get($clientObj[0]->risk_api_key.'Count'))){
                        $count = count(Cache::get($clientObj[0]->risk_api_key.'Count'));
                        $dbCount = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT num_of_consumed_requests FROM clients WHERE key = '".$clientObj[0]->key."';"));
                        $count = $count + $dbCount[0]->num_of_consumed_requests;
                        DB::select(DB::raw('UPDATE clients SET num_of_consumed_requests = '. $count .' WHERE key = '".$clientObj[0]->key."';"));
                    }
                }
            }
            Cache::flush();
        })->everyTwoMinutes();
```

Here, the clients is an array of unique keys that is stored when an API req is hit to the server, ([unique key1, unique key2...]) and key is an unique key.

*Note: We use file caching in Laravel 8+.*

Comment: You have a critical section problem. Whenever concurrent requests need to read and possibly update a shared value you need to use a [lock](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#atomic-locks)

Comment: In this case file-cache makes no sense here. You need in-memory cache that will work multiple times faster. Also locks should be used to prevent race condition

Comment: Can u give me a small example on this?